# How to scale this material

Tags: materials

I got the nodes from website. I have the below nodes and the result. How can scale the holes. As there is no nodes to scale down. I tried to unwrap and scale down in the im image editor did not work. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: when you say that the scaling didn't work, what do you mean?

Comment: If you want to scale with the UV, then use the "UV" socket instead of the "Generated" in the "Texture Coordinate" node on the left side. Or you can plug a "Mapping" node between the "Image Texture" nodes and the "Texture Coordinate" node and adjust it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/mapping.html